# Android NDK OpenCv - cvCaptureFromFile not working

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to reuse existing c/c++ OpenCv application through android NDK, but i am unable to capture video from sdcard.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("/sdcard/abc.mp4");
```

capture value is always NULL.I am using OpenCv-2.4.0. I have seen other cvCaptureFromFile questions in stackoverflow but I am unable to identify whether cvCaptureFromFile works in andrioid ndk or not.Please help.

Comment: Not familiar with this particular feature of openCV, but are you getting any errors in logcat, which may hint the cause of the problem?

Comment: It compiles with no errors in logcat.

Comment: It compile with errors AND/OR there are no errors in logcat? Which of the two?
Also, have you confirmed the file path, it might be for example "/mnt/sdcard/abc.mp4" ?

Comment: No errors in logcat. yes i have confirmed the file path in my smartphone.Even i have checked with "/mnt/sdcard/abc.mp4" in another phone it was not working.

Comment: very hard to come up with an answer without additional information... Reading the documentation - the reason may also lay in the file type and codecs supported by the system: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: Any sample code on cvCaptureFromFile for android Ndk would of great help.

Comment: @swethakini I couldn't find a ready sample using cvCaptureFromFile, but there are several examples using it with the same logic.
Can I suggest trying to change the video with an avi and an mpg to see if that brings any change, I still think it may be codec related? Finally, if not confidential - would you share your project so we could test and debug first hand?

Comment: @user1368342 I need to load video..For image cvLoadImage() works fine..